# Getting all selected checkboxes values using ajax and jsp/servlets?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a jsp/serlvet application. I have a page with a list of inputs as checkboxes . I want to send values of selected buttons to a servlet using ajax/jquery. In the servlet , I want to extract these values and use them .
**for example:**

- The user checks some checkboxes , for example, list of messages.
- He/She presses Delete **Link** to delete selected messages.

I searched and found something like this :

```
$("#inboxDeleteSelected").click(function(){
    var data = { 'checkBoxList[]' : []};
    var list=$(":input:checkbox:checked"); // getting all selected checkboxes.
    $(list.each(function() {
       data['checkBoxList[]'].push($(this).val());
    }));
    $.post("servlet?do=deleteSelected",data,function(d){
        // do something here
    });
});
```

**My questions:**

- How can I send selected checkboxes values to a servlet ?
- How can I extract these values in the servlet ?

**Note:**

I don't use submit button to submit the selected checkboxes,Indeed I use link/anchor to send those values .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. They are sent using their name, repeated:

   ```
   servlet?do=deleteSelected&checkboxGroup=value1&checkboxGroup=value2
   ```

   You can see that with the following simple html (after you press the submit button, take a look at the address bar):

   ```
   <form method="get">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="2" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="3" />
   <input type="submit" />
   </form>
   ```
2. You obtain them using:

   ```
   String[] values = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");
   ```